# Continuous map on locally compact space is closed?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous surjective (onto) function where $X$ and $Y$ are both locally compact.  Is $f$ necessarily closed?  That is, does $f$ map closed sets to closed sets.   I have tried making counterexamples but am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb R^2$ is locally compact, and the projection function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x$ is continuous but not closed: e.g., the graph of $y=\frac1x$ is a closed set whose image under $f$ is $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, which is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=\arctan x+x\sin(\pi x)$. This is a surjective continuous function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, and $f\left[\Bbb Z\right]$ is not closed.

Comment: Had a very similar idea: With $f(x)= x \sin(x-|x|) + \arctan(x)$, not even $f([0,\infty))$ ist closed.